# Get Visible Signature from a PDF using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, image-extraction

Is it possible to extract the visible signature (image of capture) of an signed PDF with itext?

Workflow:

1. list all signatures of a file
2. show with signatures include an visible signature
3. show which are valid
4. extract images of signatures (need to extract correct image for each signature)

1+3:

```
for (String name:af.getSignatureNames()) {
    AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
    PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);
}
```

2:
will be solved with 4

4:
Here begins the trouble. How is it possible to get the link to the correct field (annotation) and how can I  render the embedded data as image (could also be implemented with an external image libary if needed).

I've found out how to get the *Item*, but not a link to Image Stream or  *PdfSignatureAppearance*:

```
Item field = af.getFieldItem(name);
```

Thanks for your help. Greets.

Comment: iText does not provide bitmap rendering capabilities out of the box.

Comment: Found a solution with my prefered PDF framework (PDFBox): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949888/get-visible-signature-from-a-pdf-using-pdfbox