# how to parse pdf's "vector image" to a bitmap and how to extract image in page by page through pdfbox or Itext java libries

Tags: forms, pdf, itext, pdfbox

As the title, How I to do that?.

May any one tell me? Thank you a lot :)

this is the pdf file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63353043/s.pdf

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. Are you trying to extract an existing image from a PDF? Have you tried anything? Can you post a code sample of what you've tried?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17145649/1729265) shows how to render an annotation xobject to a bitmap image using pdfbox. Do you mean something along those lines?

Comment: Hi , @Chris Haas  , sorry, My English is no good,So I dcription not complete.
I wanna extract this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63353043/s.pdf , I tried using pdfbox commline tool to extractImage, But it is nothing. 
btw, if I wanna parse pdf image page by page using padbox that how I to do that?

Comment: Your file is pure vector graphics, it does not contain any XObjects. I just looked at it with the PDFDebugger command line tool.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr , yup it's exactly, I just wanna parse the vector graphics that it's any method to do that?.

 btw, if I wanna parse pdf image page by page using padbox that how I to do that?

Comment: To convert pages to image, see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/apache-pdfbox-convert-pdf-to-images . "Parse the vector graphics" is kindof unclear, you could get the page content stream and then use PDFStreamParser, but this will just give you a list of tokens; you need to read the PDF specification to know what each operator means. I'd recommend you edit your question to clarify what you need and why. Re language, if possible, have a good friend help you. The RemoveAllText.java in the source code download is an example to use the stream parser.

Comment: Now after editing your question is a duplicate of the question from the link in my previous comment. I suggest you try that code, to see if it is what you need.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  thank you, you help me fully T_T , Thank you a lot......

I'm certain conpany web developer in Tainwan, thoes requrement above is about PDF convert to Epub(e-book) because many of pdf to html tool are not custom,My conpany wants to self-sufficient.