# Extract signature image from PDF signed with Adobe Sign

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, adobe-sign, adobe-pdfservices

I'm trying to extract the signature image from a PDF signed with Adobe Sign. Not sure how Adobe adds this image.

[image]

I have tested in Java with iText and PDFBox. Normally when you traverse through the PDF structure with some tools e.g iText RUPS you can find the images like the visible signature and even download it directly in the tool. I didn't find it in this case. I did find though the XObject what I think holds the signature image.

[image]

The stream looks like this:

```
q
    q
        0.07843 0.45098 0.90196 RG
        0.07843 0.45098 0.90196 rg
        1 w
        q
            BT
                1 0 0 1 0 1.78 Tm
                /F1 6 Tf
                0.07843 0.45098 0.90196 rg
                ({0009002000270027002a00010018002a002d0027001f00010497000200300022000104400443047600010441043f044104420001044004410477043f044300010008000e001506d404410498}) Tj
                0 g
            ET
        Q
        0 8.28 m
            103.55 8.28 l
        S
    Q
    0 0 0 RG
    0 0 0 rg
    q
        1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
        /Xf2 Do
    Q
Q
```

And has a reference to Xf2 which looks like this:

```
1 J
1 j
1.000 w
30.315 10.580 m
    30.315 10.580 30.315 10.580 30.315 10.587 c
S
1.000 w
30.315 10.587 m
    30.315 10.594 30.315 10.608 30.315 10.627 c
S
1.000 w
30.315 10.627 m
    30.315 10.646 30.315 10.670 30.315 10.683 c
S
...
```

Can this be extracted as an image?

---

Proof of concept with PDFBox:

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {

            PDAnnotation annotation = document.getPage(0).getAnnotations().get(0);
            PDResources resources = annotation.getPage().getResources();
            Iterator<COSName> names = resources.getXObjectNames().iterator();
            PDXObject xi3Object = resources.getXObject(names.next());
            PDStream xi3Stream = xi3Object.getStream();

// OR 

            COSDictionary page = (COSDictionary) document.getDocument().getObjectsByType(COSName.ANNOT).get(0)
                    .getDictionaryObject(COSName.P);
            COSDictionary resources = (COSDictionary) page.getItem(COSName.RESOURCES);
            COSDictionary xObject = (COSDictionary) resources.getItem(COSName.XOBJECT);
            COSObject xi3Object = (COSObject) xObject.getItem("Xi3");
            COSStream xi3Stream = (COSStream) xi3Object.getObject();

            PDFormXObject pdFormXObject = new PDFormXObject(xi3Stream);

            PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(pdFormXObject.getBBox().getWidth(),
                    pdFormXObject.getBBox().getHeight()));

            try (PDDocument tempDocument = new PDDocument()) {

                PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(tempDocument, page);
                AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
                affineTransform.setToTranslation(0, 0);
                affineTransform.setToScale(0.75d, 0.75d);
                pdFormXObject.setMatrix(affineTransform);
                contents.drawForm(pdFormXObject);
                contents.restoreGraphicsState();
                contents.close();
                tempDocument.addPage(page);
                PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(tempDocument);
                BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 600);
                try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
                    return baos.toByteArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you say "image", you appear to think only of *bitmap images*. But there also are other kinds of images, in particular *vector graphics images* which are very well suited to show signatures. What you found in that file are vector graphics instructions laying out a path and stroking it.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I came to the same conclusion. I understood they are vector graphics. Is it possible to extract and convert them to bitmap format?

Comment: @KJ I would like to do all this in Java with PDFBox or iText.

Comment: Does the `AnnotationDrawer` for pdfbox from [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145649/1729265) help? It's being implemented based on pdfbox 1.8.2 but the concept should still be usable with the current pdfbox 3.

Comment: @mkl I have tried that but that code is really outdated. I can maybe test it again. I missed that they have released 3.0.

Comment: @mkl I have tested with PDFBox version 1.82 just to see if it works at all but unfortunately no. `PDAppearanceDictionary appearDictionary = annotation.getAppearance();` is null.

Comment: *"I have tested with PDFBox version 1.82 just to see if it works at all but unfortunately no."* - Well, apparently the signature appearances you are after are not annotation appearances but generic XObjects. Thus, you'll have to change the code to work on XObject resources of the page (maybe even recursively) instead on annotation appearances. As you don't share an example file, this is a bit of guesswork for me...

Comment: @mkl I have uploaded a test file here: https://file.io/5UQcJejlOWzQ

Comment: Ok, nested XObjects, so recursing through page XObject Resources is necessary. I'll take a look later this week.

Comment: Thanks! They are nested but they always have the same id Xi3 and Xf2 so a really ugly solution is like: `COSDictionary t = (COSDictionary) document.getDocument().getObjectsByType(COSName.ANNOT).get(0).getDictionaryObject(COSName.P); COSDictionary resources = (COSDictionary) t.getItem(COSName.RESOURCES); COSDictionary xObject = (COSDictionary) resources.getItem(COSName.XOBJECT); COSObject xObjectXi3 = (COSObject) xObject.getItem("Xi3"); COSDictionary resourcesXi3 = (COSDictionary) xObjectXi3.getItem(COSName.RESOURCES);...` But yes this would stop working if they change their implementation.

Comment: *"But yes this would stop working if they change their implementation"* - These scribbles are not marked in a distinct, standardized manner. Thus, no matter how you extract them, it will always be possible that Adobe changes the implementation in a way that breaks your extraction. (Unless you train some AI to recognize where the signature scribbles are and render exactly those regions. But then the AI may sometimes err...)

Answer (score 1):

Your Question was can a signature squiggle (vector graphic) be extracted as an image?

So there are more unknows than answers, in such a question, like where do you need the extraction to be or converted into?

Here on left we can see the multiple components of a signature annotation. and once we know what nested object is the artwork (here number 14 0 obj) we can copy the stream data into another PDF. As seen on the right.

[image]

since it is a screen graphic we can copy and paste to any graphics application and save in any image format you wish. However to maintain the simplicity of the source it is best copied into an SVG editor like Inkscape.

Or simpler yet since it is now an isolated PDF object simply convert to SVG for forensic use in a web page, or on the bosses debit account,  etc. `mutool convert -o output.svg input.pdf`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful ideas! I will experiment a little bit more with the SVG idea because if I understand right it isn't enough to just copy to an SVG editor but translate it to SVG format and even though it isn't that simple. I went with the to PDF and then to image idea right now. Added a sample code to my question. I will try to make it more intelligent but it works as it is know.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the `AnnotationDrawer` from [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145649/1729265), generalized to work for arbitrary form XObjects, could be used to render the pen signatures from Adobe Acrobat Sign signed documents to separate bitmap images.

That annotation drawer can be generalized (and ported to PDFBox 3) as follows:

```java
public class ContentStreamRenderer extends PDFRenderer {
    public ContentStreamRenderer(PDDocument document) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        super(document);
        pageImageField = PDFRenderer.class.getDeclaredField("pageImage");
        pageImageField.setAccessible(true);
        pageDrawerParametersConstructor = (Constructor<PageDrawerParameters>) PageDrawerParameters.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
        pageDrawerParametersConstructor.setAccessible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected PageDrawer createPageDrawer(PageDrawerParameters parameters) throws IOException {
        PageDrawer pageDrawer = new ContentStreamPageDrawer(parameters);
        pageDrawer.setAnnotationFilter(getAnnotationsFilter());
        return pageDrawer;
    }

    public BufferedImage renderImage(PDPage page, PDContentStream contentStream, float scale, ImageType imageType, RenderDestination destination) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {
        try {
            PDRectangle bBox = contentStream.getBBox();
            Rectangle2D bounds = bBox.transform(contentStream.getMatrix()).getBounds2D();
            bBox = new PDRectangle((float)bounds.getMinX(), (float)bounds.getMinY(), (float)bounds.getWidth(), (float)bounds.getHeight());
            
            float widthPt = bBox.getWidth();
            float heightPt = bBox.getHeight();

            // PDFBOX-4306 avoid single blank pixel line on the right or on the bottom
            int widthPx = (int) Math.max(Math.floor(widthPt * scale), 1);
            int heightPx = (int) Math.max(Math.floor(heightPt * scale), 1);

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(widthPx, heightPx, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            pageImageField.set(this, image);

            // use a transparent background if the image type supports alpha
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            g.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            g.scale(scale, scale);

            RenderingHints actualRenderingHints =
                    getRenderingHints() == null ? createDefaultRenderingHints(g) : getRenderingHints();
            PageDrawerParameters parameters =
                    pageDrawerParametersConstructor.newInstance(this, page, isSubsamplingAllowed(), destination,
                            actualRenderingHints, getImageDownscalingOptimizationThreshold());
            PageDrawer drawer = createPageDrawer(parameters);
            if (drawer instanceof ContentStreamPageDrawer) {
                ((ContentStreamPageDrawer)drawer).setContentStream(contentStream);
            }
            drawer.drawPage(g, bBox);

            g.dispose();

            if (imageType != ImageType.ARGB)
            {
                int biType = -1;
                switch (imageType) {
                case ARGB:   biType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB; break;
                case BGR:    biType = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR; break;
                case BINARY: biType = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY; break;
                case GRAY:   biType = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY; break;
                case RGB:    biType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB; break;
                }
                BufferedImage newImage = 
                        new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), biType);
                Graphics2D dstGraphics = newImage.createGraphics();
                dstGraphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                dstGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                dstGraphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                dstGraphics.dispose();
                image = newImage;
            }

            return image;
        } finally {
            pageImageField.set(this, null);
        }
    }

    private RenderingHints createDefaultRenderingHints(Graphics2D graphics)
    {
        RenderingHints r = new RenderingHints(null);
        r.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        r.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        r.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        return r;
    }

    final Field pageImageField;
    final Constructor<PageDrawerParameters> pageDrawerParametersConstructor;
}
```

*([ContentStreamRenderer](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/render/ContentStreamRenderer.java#L33) class derived from `PDFRenderer`)*

with this helper class

```java
public class ContentStreamPageDrawer extends PageDrawer {
    public ContentStreamPageDrawer(PageDrawerParameters parameters) throws IOException {
        super(parameters);
    }

    public PDContentStream getContentStream() {
        return contentStream;
    }

    public void setContentStream(PDContentStream contentStream) {
        this.contentStream = contentStream;
    }

    //
    // Overrides that make drawPage only draw the set content stream
    // if one is set. Otherwise, these overrides delegate to PageDrawer.
    //
    @Override
    public void processPage(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        if (contentStream == null) {
            super.processPage(page);
        } else {
            processChildStream(contentStream, page);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showAnnotation(PDAnnotation annotation) throws IOException {
        if (contentStream == null) {
            super.showAnnotation(annotation);
        }
    }

    PDContentStream contentStream = null;
}
```

*([ContentStreamPageDrawer](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/render/ContentStreamPageDrawer.java#L23C1-L57C2) helper of `ContentStreamRenderer`)*

These classes constitute a customization of the standard PDFBox PDF renderer and page drawer, a generalization to render individual content streams of a PDF.

Unfortunately PDFBox has made many member variables and methods private or at least package protected. As I didn't want to copy the whole classes, I, therefore, had to use reflection which will not work in some contexts. (Keeping members hidden away like that really is a PITA...)

To render the form XObjects in the example PDF signed using Adobe Acrobat Sign, you can use those classes like this:

```java
PDDocument pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(PDF_SOURCE)
ContentStreamRenderer renderer = new ContentStreamRenderer(pdDocument);
PDPage pdPage = pdDocument.getPage(0);
PDResources pdResources = pdPage.getResources();

for (COSName xObjectName : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
    PDXObject pdXObject = pdResources.getXObject(xObjectName);
    if (pdXObject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
        PDFormXObject pdFormXObject = (PDFormXObject) pdXObject;
        BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImage(pdPage, pdFormXObject, 4, ImageType.RGB, RenderDestination.VIEW);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test_document_signed-1-" + xObjectName.getName() + ".png"));

        PDResources innerResources = pdFormXObject.getResources();
        for (COSName innerXObjectName : innerResources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject innerXObject = innerResources.getXObject(innerXObjectName);
            if (innerXObject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
                PDFormXObject innerFormXObject = (PDFormXObject) innerXObject;
                image = renderer.renderImage(pdPage, innerFormXObject, 4, ImageType.RGB, RenderDestination.VIEW);
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test_document_signed-1-" + xObjectName.getName() + "-" + innerXObjectName.getName() + ".png"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([RenderAcrobatSignSignatures](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/render/RenderAcrobatSignSignatures.java#L47) test `testRenderTestDocumentSigned`)*

The results:

[image: test_document_signed-1-Xi3.png]

[image: test_document_signed-1-Xi3-Xf2.png]

[image: test_document_signed-1-Xi4.png]

---

In your proof of concept you extract the form XObjects and draw them on pages of temporary PDFs. That approach has the advantage of not needing reflection (or copying the whole PDFBox rendering classes). It may have the disadvantage, though, of requiring more resources.

Comment: Thanks! I have tested it and it works fine. Also compatible with PDFBox 2.x the only difference is how you load the PDDocument.